# Pandoc - Convert from Markdown to PDF and Set File Name From Metadata Title

Tags: pandoc

YAML Metada looks like this

```
---
Tag: tag1, tag2
title: "Title I want to use"
Status: active
Name: "John Smith"
---
```

I currently use this command

```
for f in *.md; do pandoc "$f" -o "${f%.md}.pdf"; done
```

How do I set the command so that the file name will be taken from the title metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a helper file `title.plain` with content

```
$title$
```

With that, the following command should do:

```sh
for f in *.md; do
  pandoc "$f" -o "$(pandoc --template=title.plain -t plain "$f")".pdf
done
```

Comment: Thank you. I first had to create a folder where to put the template. In terminal do

 ```mkdir -p ~/.pandoc/templates```

Then move or create a text file "title.plain" and add ```$title$``` as content.